# Django-allauth login on fb canvas

Tags: python, django, angularjs, facebook

I've been trying to connect user on my fb canvas app.

I've implemented django-allauth fb login on my website. In fb canvas app, I'm trying to get user as already logged in since user has already been connected on fb.

Is there any way to make it using django-allauth?

Comment: I think it should automatically recognize the user. What's in your **request.user**?

Comment: That's right, but I need to make request in order to get user in request. It cannot be embedded just according to first access. I gotta call /accounts/facebook/login/ endpoint .

Answer (score 0):

The answer is yes.

Just simply setup your fb canvas url to this:

`https://yourdomain.com/your-allauth-url/facebook/login/?process=login`

With this, your canvas app visitor will go through the allauth facebook login process. If the user has connected to your app it will redirect him/her to the login redirect url you have specified in your settings. Otherwise it will just ask him to allow the facebook connection.

Comment: yap, but this is GET method, and first access from canvas url is POST method. So, I'm not able just to pass this URL.

Comment: So why don't you redirect to this url if the user is not authenticated?

Comment: It doesn't work, It calls the endpoint, but it doesn't get any callback response. I think that I cannot hack it, I'd need a logic to create any user according #signed_request that I've got through fb canvas.

Comment: Are you able to get the user's access token?

Comment: I'm trying to achieve it. Through signed_request I should be able to get it, but I'm just getting basic signed_request data without user_id and oauth_token.

Comment: What's happening exactly if you call the facebook login url? It doesn't redirect you back?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/66757/discussion-between-prog-dusan-and-martincpt).

Answer (score 0):

One possible approach would be:

```
class FacebookCanvasLoginView(View):
    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        social_app = SocialApp.objects.filter(provider='facebook').first()
        signed_request = parse_signed_request(request.POST.get('signed_request'), str(social_app.secret))
        token = SocialToken(app=social_app, token=signed_request['oauth_token'])

        login = fb_complete_login(request, social_app, token)
        login.token = token
        login.state = SocialLogin.state_from_request(request)

        return complete_social_login(request, login)
```

Did you finally find a solution for this problem? If you find another solution than the one that I proposed it would be great if you can share it here.